# 'Add New User' works in Development, not in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Background:  'Add User' portion of an app works perfectly on two separate development machines, running two different OSes: Dev Machine 1 is a Mac running Catalina (10.15), Dev machine 2 is running an Ubuntu derivative (Pop!_OS 19.10).  After pushing to a Digital Ocean Dokku server the 'Add User' functionality fails without error; hitting the submit button does nothing.  'Edit User' works in production, as well as dev.

The code is being managed via git, with no complications on that part.  Therefore, the identical code is on three machines.

I rely on Devise for my user setup; however, skip registrations in order to restrict the public from creating an account. Instead I rely on cancancan with a role to create users. This all works in development, but I cannot see a proper error in production, it simply does a render :action => :new with no explicit error. I use Dokku, Rails 6.03 with Ruby Version 2.7.1

Development Log

```
 Started POST "/user_managements" for ::1 at 2021-01-23 13:30:48 -0500
Processing by UsersController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"zr4lstDZAfXC3dTf1UADmoa6jbZl5HNQZCuDDdnWBuqa32LtAnadmjYHN+PnVUfs6RFVwcJ03KtpaE/l5osdiQ==", "user"=>{"email"=>"alice@wonderland.com", "first_name"=>"Alice", "last_name"=>"Wonderland", "phone_number"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "superadmin_role"=>"0", "supervisor_role"=>"0", "user_role"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "stores"
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:33:in `set_search'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:22:in `create'
  User Exists? (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "alice@wonderland.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:22:in `create'
  User Create (0.4ms)  ***INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at", "first_name", "last_name", "phone_number") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "alice@wonderland.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$VNfiMFc2CrDrdtsa31wXkOyhz4D4TkPVTiyDfceO62UwfZdS9fAhS"], ["created_at", "2021-01-23 18:30:49.138574"], ["updated_at", "2021-01-23 18:30:49.138574"], ["first_name", "Alice"], ["last_name", "Wonderland"], ["phone_number", ""]]***
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:22:in `create'
   (9.6ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:22:in `create'
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/user_managements
Completed 200 OK in 257ms (ActiveRecord: 11.3ms | Allocations: 8092)
```

Production Log (Note the absence of the "INSERT" statement.)

```
 Started POST "/user_managements" for 173.170.223.213 at 2021-01-23 17:35:02 +0000
2021-01-23T17:35:02.954032036Z app[web.1]: I, [2021-01-23T17:35:02.953856 #10]  INFO -- : [6c93c1d9-2122-4cda-8f39-ed32e42b39e0] Processing by UsersController#create as JS
2021-01-23T17:35:02.954859299Z app[web.1]: I, [2021-01-23T17:35:02.954744 #10]  INFO -- : [6c93c1d9-2122-4cda-8f39-ed32e42b39e0]   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"IlDwRv3r8Qv51qXyg+roq5FiuJ+pbJjsZTlWjq50hxVKtGHptRSusL7Slf0oNiqqwN1VADhGrSbdt7GZVMp9rg==", "user"=>{"email"=>"alice@wonderland.com", "first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "phone_number"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "superadmin_role"=>"0", "supervisor_role"=>"0", "user_role"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
2021-01-23T17:35:02.959242127Z app[web.1]: D, [2021-01-23T17:35:02.959108 #10] DEBUG -- : [6c93c1d9-2122-4cda-8f39-ed32e42b39e0]   User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2021-01-23T17:35:02.964234692Z app[web.1]: D, [2021-01-23T17:35:02.964099 #10] DEBUG -- : [6c93c1d9-2122-4cda-8f39-ed32e42b39e0]    (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "stores"
2021-01-23T17:35:02.983197832Z app[web.1]: I, [2021-01-23T17:35:02.982997 #10]  INFO -- : [6c93c1d9-2122-4cda-8f39-ed32e42b39e0]   Rendering users/new.html.erb within layouts/application
2021-01-23T17:35:02.985854583Z app[web.1]: I, [2021-01-23T17:35:02.985747 #10]  INFO -- : [6c93c1d9-2122-4cda-8f39-ed32e42b39e0]   Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.7ms | Allocations: 905)
2021-01-23T17:35:02.989341142Z app[web.1]: I, [2021-01-23T17:35:02.989236 #10]  INFO -- : [6c93c1d9-2122-4cda-8f39-ed32e42b39e0] Completed 200 OK in 34ms (Views: 6.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms | Allocations: 4898)
```

=== relevant code begins below ===

Routes

```
    resources :paper_routes

  get 'stores/active/' => 'stores#active'
  get 'stores/inactive/' => 'stores#inactive'

  resources :stores do
    post :update_row_order, on: :collection
    resources :sheets
    collection do
    match 'search' => 'stores#search', via: [:get, :post], as: :search
    end
  end

  resources :user_managements, :controller => 'users'

  devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations], controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions", passwords: "users/passwords" }

  as :user do
    root 'users/sessions#new'
    get 'users/edit' => 'users/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_user_registration'
    put 'user' => 'users/registrations#update', :as => 'user_registration'
  end

 get 'dashboard' => 'home#index', as: 'dashboard'
 get 'reports' => 'reports#index', as: 'reports'
end
```

controllers/users_controller.rb

```
    def new
    @user = User.new
        respond_to do |format|
        format.html 
        format.json
      end
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
            if @user.save 
              flash[:notice] = 'User created'
              redirect_to user_managements_path and return
            else
              flash.now[:warning] = 'There were problems when trying to create a new User'
              render :action => :new
            end
   end

  def edit
    @user = User.find params[:id]
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html 
        format.json
      end
  end

 def update
  @user = User.find params[:id]
      if @user.update_attributes user_params
            flash[:notice] = 'User has been updated'
            redirect_to user_managements_path and return
        else
            flash.now[:warning] = 'There were problems when trying to update this User'
            render :action => :edit
        end
 end

(...)

 def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:id, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :superadmin_role, :supervisor_role, :user_role, :first_name, :last_name, :phone_number)
 end
```

/views/users/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_with model: @user, url: user_managements_path, class: "form-group" do |f| %>
<div class="row pt-3">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="field">
  <%= label_tag(:name, "Email") %>
  <%= f.text_field :email, :class => "form-control", :type => "text" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
(...)
```

/views/users/edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_with model: @user, url: user_management_path(@user), class: "form-group" do |f| %>

<div class="row pt-3">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="field">
  <%= label_tag(:name, "Email") %>
  <%= f.text_field :email, :class => "form-control", :type => "text" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
(...)
```

Comment: Check the logs.

Comment: There is nothing evident in syslog or nginx.  I've added the production and development dokku logs from the last attempt.  The takeaway here is that there is no INSERT statement occuring on the production server.

Comment: It's rendering the `new` template, so `@user.save` is failing, how do you handle de error when the object fails to be saved? do you have a `new.js` view?

Comment: @arieljuod - I don't have a new.js I do a render new with flash message.  I don't get an error in the logs and my flash message is generic.  This works fine in development.  Confused!

Comment: is it ok that your params in production have first_name and last_name as empty strings? you are comparing (or at least showing) two different requests in your question when comparing dev and production

Comment: @arieljuod Yes, they are allowed to be empty.

Comment: I would add `local: true` to the form so that it does not send a JS request which will remove a completely unnecessary level of debugging complexity even if it does not fix the issue. I can't say that the rest o the form makes any sense either through. Why do you have a label and mismatching input? `:type => "text"` is also completely superflouos as are the `and return` all over that controller.

Comment: @max Thank you! I've cleaned up the code removing everything you've recommended.  I've added local: true as well.  Still having the same issue, so if you have any more insights, I'm all ears (or, eyes :) ).  Keep in mind, it works perfectly on the development machines.  Could this trouble be with Devise in the production environment?

Comment: I don't think I (or anybody else) can actually  get any farther with this code. I mean it's impossible to reproduce this  and the only thing I can think of is if that User#save has been modified or something else really strange in the model unless it's really due to the machines running different code - for example if they are using different branches.

Comment: I would recommend you to open the browser's dev tools, go to the network tab and check the actual response when you do that request, you may have something useful as a response content.

Comment: It's most likely related to this query: `SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]`.  It might be running as some sort of authentication request, and it should not be for `create`. If you should be authenticated as a user to create a user, perhaps the User with id = 2 doesn't exist in your production database. You aren't even running `User.new(user_params)` because the email existence check isn't happening.

Comment: Thank you everyone so much for all of your input!  I've found the answer which had to do with the order of Devise and the users controller inside of the routes.rb file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone has any insight as to *why* this worked in development but not production, I'd love to know.  Seems like it had to do with not loading Devise first.

The original code in routes.rb:

```
resources :user_managements, :controller => 'users'
devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations], controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions", passwords: "users/passwords" }
```

I switched the order around to:

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations], controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions", passwords: "users/passwords" }
resources :user_managements, :controller => 'users'
```

Which solved the problem.  Thank you again, @idmean, @arieljuod, @max and @jim!